# Why are numbers not pasting correctly in an HTML input field?

Tags: html, input-field

I am trying to paste a very long list of numbers, comma separated, into an HTML input field. It's a list of 100,000 numbers to be exact. I double checked that it was the correct length by pasting it into a word counter.

The problem is, after pasting the list of numbers into the input field, it shows some whitespace which I know is not copied to my clipboard. And, when I copy the pasted numbers from the input field, it copies the 100,000 numbers correctly. But for some reason it shows up with whitespace in the input field, and my input-validation function gives an alert that it contains non-digits and non-comma characters. I tried setting the `maxlength` of the input to 1,000,000 but that didn't work. Does anyone know why the input field is not correctly 'storing' my list of numbers?

Here is how the input field looks after pasting the number list:

[image: picture of incorrectly displayed numbers in input field]

(note the extra whitespace)

Html:

```
<label for="array_input">Array:</label>
<input type="text" name="array_input" id="array_input" value="" maxlength="1000000">
```

and reading the input value with jQuery/JS:

```
let arrayField = $('#array_input').val()
inputArray = arrayField.split(',').map(a => parseInt(a))
bubbleSort(inputArray)
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  ...
}
```

This works fine for lists of a few, or even ten thousand numbers, but for some reason pasting 100,000 adds some whitespace.

Screenshot of working case:
[image]

(no extra whitespace)

Comment: Hi, interesting, it looks like it's printing the array with comma delimiters for some reason. Is the value somehow being replaced with the text representation of the array?

Comment: @IronMan Not sure I understand. The list of numbers that I'm trying to paste already contains commas. And the `arrayField` variable is only later transformed into an actual array. It's pasted into the input field as text.

Comment: You should post full attempt with less then  100,000 numbers as example sample, something is fishy in your whole process. Make [mre] , And arrays are posted comma separated by default.

Comment: @ikiK I've added some minimal Javascript to show the processing of input value. It pastes, runs, and returns just as expected with fewer numbers, but for some reason with a list of 100,000 it is adding whitespace.

Comment: Doubt no one will be able to help if can not re-produce the problem and without seeing sample data... Try to trim all arrays. And why do you even posting such amount of numbers into input? I have to ask.

Comment: Maybe your array contains white space, you might wanna take a look. If this aint the case, use regex to filter white space.